# MongoDB/Mongoose querying at current date?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Hi i'm trying to do a query to get results for one specific userId and it has to show for all future dates including now.date sorted from the most recent to the future.

Here is my collection:

```
 {
   "_id": "206d",
   "seatNumber": "76",
   "startDate": "2022-07-06T22:00:00.000Z",
   "userId": "34B24"
},
{
   "_id": "624a",
   "seatNumber": "12",
   "userId": "34B24",
   "startDate": "2021-07-06T22:00:00.000Z"
}
```

```
exports.getMyReservations = (req, res, next) => {
 Reservations.find( {userId: req.params.userId}).where('startDate':{$gt:Date.now()}).sort(asc)}
```

But it's not working on postman. It supposed to show the first document result
Please help

Comment: sort(asc) => must be 'asc', a string

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the date to ISO string with the help of javascript's toISOString() method

```
Reservations.find({userId: req.params.userId,
  "startDate": {$gt: new Date().toISOString()}
}).sort({})
```

[image: query which I tried in Robo3t (GUI for MongoDB)]

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: I have edited the answer and pasted the output, did you get any error after running the query?